# How to search with list comprehension for a reflexive relation

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am at the moment learning how to code python. Now I have to make a list comprehension to check if some input is reflexive.
For example:
I give a function a list with 3 numbers `[4,5,6]` and I have another input list with some values `[(4,4), (4,6), (5,5), (5,6), (6,6)]` the answer is here true because I have all relevant values `[(4,4),(5,5),(6,6)]` which means its reflexive. How can I implement a list comprehension which is searching for `(4,4)`,(5,5) and (6,6) in this second list and takes the values from the first list?
I tried it now for 4 hours and I don't have any progress. So can you give me some advice how to implement it?

Comment: Can you implement it if you don't use a list comprehension?  You have to show _some_ effort, this is not a code writing service...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do that:

```
l1 = [4,5,6]
l2 = [(4,4), (4,6), (5,5), (5,6), (6,6)]

all([(x,x) in l2 for x in l1])
#==> True
```

Comment: Thank you, you really really helped me

Comment: If it solved your question, it would be great if you could accept the answer.